# Prove that with the subspace metric $Y\cap Z$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $Y, Z\subseteq X$ so that with the subspace metric $Y$ and $Z$ are complete. Prove that with the subspace metric $Y\cap Z$ is complete.

Since $Y$ and $Z$ are complete every Cauchy sequence in $Y$ and $Z$ converges.

So $\exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n,m > N_1$ implies $d(y_n,y_m)< \epsilon$

And $\exists N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n,m > N_2$ implies $d(z_n,z_m)< \epsilon$.

But i'm confused on how to represent a cauchy sequence in $Y\cap Z$  to prove that it converges.

Comment: The Cauchiness of a sequence doesn't depend in which subspace(s) the sequence lies. A Cauchy sequence in $Y \cap Z$ is Cauchy in $Y$, in $Z$, and in $X$. The question is, can you construct a limit for this sequence that lies in $Y \cap Z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{a_n\}\subset Y\cap Z$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y\cap Z$. It has a limit $y$ in $Y$ as a Cauchy sequence in $Y$, and also a limit $z$ in $Z$ because it is Cauchy in $Z$. It remains to show $y=z\in\ Y\cap Z$.

Comment: since the limit of convergent sequences are unique, then y=z?

Comment: Yes, and be aware that this actually follows from the axiom of a metric that $d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$. Sometimes one encounters (pesudo-) metrics that don't satisfy this and then limit may not be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Hints (all subspaces with the induced metric):

1. a complete subspace of a metric space is closed;
2. a closed subspace of a complete metric space is complete.

Comment: egreg.To the point!

Answer (score 0):

Attempt:

Let $x_n $ a Cauchy sequence in $Y \cap Z$.

$x_n$ is  Cauchy in $Y$, since complete, has a limit $y \in Y$.

$x_n$ is Cauchy in $Z$, since complete, has a limit $z \in Z$.

Assume $z \not =y$.

Then $d(z,y) >0$.

Choose $\epsilon = d(z,y)/4$.

There is a $n_1$ s.t. for $n\ge n_1$

$d(x_n, y) <\epsilon$.

There is a $n_2$ s.t. for $n\ge n_2$

$d(x_n, z) < \epsilon$.

For $n > \max(n_1,n_2)$ we have:

$d(y,z)< d(y,x_n) +d(x_n,z) < $

$2\epsilon= d(y,z)/2$

Contradiction.

Hence $y=z$, and $l:= y=z \in Y \cap Z$.